# Which powers are affected by increased "Restoration and Defense"?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

There's a modifier that shows up on perks and [profiles](http://www.gameskinny.com/jf2k7/mass-effect-andromeda-guide-profile-bonuses) that improves "Restoration and Defense". For example, the Explorer profile gives

> +15% Power Restoration and Defense

And the Engineer profile gives

> 20% Tech Restoration and Defense

That's completely unclear. I tried to figure out what it does. According to the [gosunoob article Mass Effect Andromeda stats – what do they mean and do?](http://www.gosunoob.com/mass-effect-andromeda/me-andromeda-stats-overview/), it has this effect:

> Your healing and buffs, including protective powers (Backlash) are affected by this stat.

It's still not clear to me what exactly it does, or which powers it affects.

I assume that the Explorer buff affects eligible Combat, Tech, and Biotic powers, and that the Engineer one only affects eligible Tech powers, but **which powers are even eligible, and exactly how are they affected?**

Comment: Haven't played so I don't know for sure but my best guess is cool-down times for active abilities, and a percentage boost to passive perks.

Comment: @n_palum I initially was thinking cooldown times myself, but based on that description that doesn't sound right. I have an ability that restores some of my shields. I think it's supposed to increase how much of my shields are restored. Probably.

Comment: Like I said, could be passive stuff like that. If the ability is one you can activate, then I image it is CD, but if it passively restores shields, I imagine it's a boost to the restoration total/speed.

Comment: Backlash gives you Eagis shield in front of you, it has a limited amount of HP. This modifier increases Eagis' HP. That's the "Defence" part of the modifier

Answer (score 3):

*Health Regeneration* and *Shield Regeneration* are **not** affected by *Power Restoration and Defense*.

It's reasonable to assume that other stats that affect health or shields but lack the *Restoration* keyword are unaffected as well.

I tested whether or not *Regeneration* was affected via the [Team Support] power with [Rank 6 - Life Support] by monitoring my health changes directly through Cheat Engine.

Swapping from [Rank 4 - Squad Offense] to [Rank 4 - Support] did not change the amount of health I regenerated at all; deploying my [Assault Turret] took me from 200 HP to 290 HP every time.

---

The *Defense* keyword is probably intended to cover both *Damage Resistance* and *Damage Reduction*, as it doesn't seem to actually match any other existing stats. Unfortunately this is very difficult to test as the game simply does not provide enough information.

I'm not convinced a skill like [Backlash] is covered by the *Defense* keyword despite what the [gosunoob article](http://www.gosunoob.com/mass-effect-andromeda/me-andromeda-stats-overview/) claims, though the [Rank 6 - Shield Resurgence] upgrade **is** covered by the *Restoration* keyword.

---

Unless you're constantly using powers like [Charge] or [Energy Drain] that explicitly grant some form of *Restoration*, the *Power Restoration and Defense* stat seems **useless**. I suggest avoiding it unless your build revolves around powers like these.

Comment: This is still incomplete information, but +1 for some useful testing.

Comment: Also, Charge and Energy Drain are two of my favorite powers, so if those are affected, then yay.

Answer (score 2):

It means abilities that restore shields or health are increased. e.g. If your ability restores 100 shield, it now restores 120 shield if you have 20% Power Restoration.

Comment: That's probably what the "restoration" part means, at a minimum. It could also apply to things like reduction in shield recharge delay. It says it improves "defense" also. We need some numbers, or tests, or a codex entry, or something other than simple speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Been playing quite a bit, but haven't delved into numbers so much. So, this is all "educated guesswork".

1. Defense. There are powers that lower enemy defense, and it seems to cumulatively increase the damage they take. That being the case, the boost could go the other way for power restoration and defense buffs.
2. Power Restoration. Seems to only apply to powers that directly increase shields. This does NOT seem to apply to Heal over time effects like regeneration or passive shield recovery. So, only powers like charge and energy drain that provide an instant boost to shields seem to be affected. As these are already large boosts that get up to or near 100% and there is no real "overcharge" for shields...the effectiveness seems to be negligible.

As there are no real direct healing effects in the game, I have started to opt for whatever option is given as an alternate to pwr rest & defense. This seems to be a better investment of points, even for my "tank" builds that use charge, backlash, & energy drain to wade through fights on legendary without bothering with cover.

I am curious to know if damage reduction improves backlash's performance, as my multiplayer asari sentinel seems to get way more service out of her lvl 3 backlash than even my legendary single player tank. My sp char is using shield capacity over damage reduction (mostly because charge and energy drain give percent of max shields, so sick). Things almost never touch my health anyway, even toe-to-toe with berzerkers and titans, but I'm curois if dr might end up being overall better than max capacity.

Comment: That's useful to know that you can skip all those bonuses and still have plenty of restoration on Legendary.